# "tibble::enframe" code no longer runs, is there a way to replicate what it does?

Tags: r

I'm running a code to format data, which goes into a rake weighting analysis.
I started to run the lines but when I get to the parts "tibble::enframe" they don't run. What does tibble do in this code? The strange thing was it did run once upon a time in past but no longer does.

the code

```
dummy_data_age <- sample(c(18:90), 100, replace = TRUE)
dummy_data_income <- sample(c(0:100000), 100, replace = TRUE)
dummy_data_gender <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE)
dummy_data_gender <- as.integer(factor(dummy_data_gender))
dummy_data_region <- sample(c("North", "East", "South", "West"), 100, replace = TRUE)
dummy_data_region <- as.integer(factor(dummy_data_region))
dummy_data_age <- tibble::enframe(dummy_data_age, "unit", "age") %>% select("age")
dummy_data_income <- tibble::enframe(dummy_data_income, "unit", "income") %>% select("income")
dummy_data_gender <- tibble::enframe(dummy_data_gender, "unit", "gender") %>% select("gender")
dummy_data_region <- tibble::enframe(dummy_data_region, "unit", "region") %>% select("region")
dummy_data_df <- bind_cols(dummy_data_age, dummy_data_income, dummy_data_gender, dummy_data_region)
```

The error message I get

```
> dummy_data_age <- tibble::enframe(dummy_data_age, "unit", "age") %>% select("age")
Error in select(., "age") : unused argument ("age")
```

Is there a way I can rewrite this code to get the same format it would have been. I'm not sure what it would have been though, as i'd just run it without checking it.
FYR it was taken from this site https://rpubs.com/anthonybmasters/survey-weights-in-r
Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't get any errors when running the code. It works fine for me. Tested with R4.0.5 and `tibble_3.1.2` and `dplyr_1.0.7`. Though I would say this is a very weird way to build a tibble that I probably wouldn't recommend. Are you sure you re-ran all lines starting at the top? This code reuses variable names in a potentially dangerous way if you run lines out of order.

Comment: I was running the latest 4.1.0. I've changed back to my previous 4.0.3 and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is another library that you have loaded which masks the `select` function. Most probably that is `MASS`.

You can reproduce the error with

```
mtcars %>% MASS::select(cyl)
```

> Error in MASS::select(., cyl) : unused argument (cyl)

Restarting R unloads the `MASS` library and it works as expected. I don't think this is R version issue. In your current setting if you used `dplyr::select` it should have worked as well since you are specifically mentioning the package to use `select` function from.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have not loaded the library for select. After adding `library(tidyverse)` before your code, it worked on my machine.

```
library(tidyverse)
dummy_data_age <- sample(c(18:90), 100, replace = TRUE)
dummy_data_income <- sample(c(0:100000), 100, replace = TRUE)
dummy_data_gender <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 100, replace = TRUE)
dummy_data_gender <- as.integer(factor(dummy_data_gender))
dummy_data_region <- sample(c("North", "East", "South", "West"), 100, replace = TRUE)
dummy_data_region <- as.integer(factor(dummy_data_region))
dummy_data_age <- tibble::enframe(dummy_data_age, "unit", "age") %>% select("age")
dummy_data_income <- tibble::enframe(dummy_data_income, "unit", "income") %>% select("income")
dummy_data_gender <- tibble::enframe(dummy_data_gender, "unit", "gender") %>% select("gender")
dummy_data_region <- tibble::enframe(dummy_data_region, "unit", "region") %>% select("region")
dummy_data_df <- bind_cols(dummy_data_age, dummy_data_income, dummy_data_gender, dummy_data_region)
```

Comment: I already tried that. It still doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine on my machine. I has also tried to update `tidyverse` packages. It still works. I would try to update `R` and `tidyverse`.

Comment: Are you running the latest, I was running the latest 4.1.0 and loaded all necessary packages but it didn't work. I've changed back to my previous 4.0.3 and now it works. Not ideal, but it'll have to do. Thanks for looking at it. Cheers

Comment: I see. I was running 4.05. I will update mine to 4.1.0 to check,

Comment: I just updated to 4.1.0. Now with R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18), tidyverse_1.3.1  and   tibble_3.1.2, the code still works fine.

Comment: ok. strange. I shut down restarted laptop, opened R with the latest. It now works, I have no explanation. The bizzareness of R. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, as long as it works!